# unexpected output with stochastic gradient descent algorithm for linear regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent, stochastic-gradient

I had an unexpected output while implementing SGD algorithm for my ML homework.

This is part of my training data which normally has 320 rows:
[image]

my dataset: https://github.com/Jangrae/csv/blob/master/carseats.csv

I first did some data preprocessing:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np

train_data = pd.read_csv('carseats_train.csv')
train_data.replace({'Yes': 1, 'No': 0}, inplace=True)
onehot_tr = pd.get_dummies(train_data['ShelveLoc'], dtype=int, prefix_sep='_', prefix='ShelveLoc')
train_data = train_data.drop('ShelveLoc', axis=1)
train_data = train_data.join(onehot_tr)


train_data_Y = train_data.iloc[:, 0]
train_data_X = train_data.drop('Sales', axis=1)
```

Then implemented the algorithm like this:

```
learning_rate = 0.01
epoch_num = 50
initial_w = 0.1
intercept = 0.1
w_matrix = np.ones((12, 1)) * initial_w

for e in range(epoch_num):
    for i in range(len(train_data_X)):

        x_i = train_data_X.iloc[i].to_numpy()
        y_i = train_data_Y.iloc[i]
        
        y_estimated = np.dot(x_i, w_matrix) + intercept
        
        grad_w = x_i.reshape(-1, 1) * (y_i - y_estimated)
    
        grad_intercept = (y_i - y_estimated)
        
       
        w_matrix = w_matrix - 2 * learning_rate * grad_w
        intercept = intercept - 2 * learning_rate * grad_intercept
        
        

print("Final weights:\n", w_matrix)
print("Final intercept:", intercept)
```

But the output was

```
Final weights:
 [[nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]]
Final intercept: [nan]
```

I run it with various learning rates and I also tried convergence threshold but still got the same result.. I couldn't find out why my code gives me nans..

Can anybody see the issue?

Comment: Picture is a very poor medium to exchange data, it wastes space, prevents other to reproduce your issue. Copy paste and format dataset or a subsample of it instead or provide a link to data. Then we could investigate it instead of having to recreate the dataset first.

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/Jangrae/csv/blob/master/carseats.csv) your data set?

Comment: @Baradrist Yes it is

Comment: @jlandercy I added my dataset to the post, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an overflow of numbers in your code. The gradients basically get too large with your setting. Consider taking more epochs and a much lower learning rate (aka. "step-size") to make your algorithm converge. I was able to get results with a learning rate of `0.000001`, but you will have to see for your training set what the "correct" number could be and also monitor the convergence (depending on the number of epochs). You could also consider an adaptive learning rate schedule.

On another note: I am not exactly sure that your equations are correct. Since you use `(y_i - y_estimated)` and not the other way around, it might be that you need to update your weights and intercept with `+` (a "double minus", if you will). Maybe you can check that again. (For comparison: [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/implement-linear-regression-stochastic-gradient-descent-scratch-python/) or [here](https://github.com/arseniyturin/SGD-From-Scratch))

PS: Your algorithm is not yet "stochastic". ;D

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But in the homework learning rate is defined so I should use 0.01 T_T So I was wondering apart from lowering the value, is there anything else that I can do so it won't overflow?

Comment: It did not solve the problem for me, but in the gradient (the derivative of the Mean Squared Error), I believe you are missing the division by the number of samples you go through (aka `len(train_data_X` in your case). And again, the derivative wrt bot x_i as well as the intercept has a `-` in it. So, when updating the weights and intercept the subtraction should become `+`, I believe.

Comment: Another problem could be that your features are "living" on very different scales. Your one-hot-encoding is always 0/1, while other features are two orders of magnitude above that. You could try to use a normalization of the data for that.

Comment: This works for me with a `learning_rate = 0.01`. Of course you then need to always provide this same normalization for new data that you give the model to predict. It's then kind of a pipeline.